# Closure inside Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

folks.

I'm learning AngularJS and i wonder, why a function inside a controller does not work as a clojure. Here is a classic example of how closure works

```
var inner;

var outer = function(x) {
    inner = function() {
        console.log(x);
    }
}

outer(3);

inner();
```

So, i expect similar behavior from this chunk of code

```
angular.module('MyModule')
.value('x', 3)
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, x) {
        $scope.showMeX = function() {
           alert(x);
        }
    }
});
```

Yet, injected variable 'x' is not accessible from inside of the 'showMeX' function. Why not?

I could guess that Angular provides access to the $scope object only to avoid messing up with some objects, that are external to the $scope, and such objects by that logic should be 'invisible'. Still, at the moment i do not understand how this works.

Any thoughts? Link to some clarifying stuff to read would be perfect.

Comment: Seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/ab537s7v/. Are you getting an error?

Comment: oh, my bad, i copypasted it from my code without trying a fiddle. thank for a quite response, this actually works and everything goes as expected. should i delete my question now, it makes no sense to keep it , right ?

Comment: Well you can post an answer to explain what happened, it is okay to make some mistakes as long as you do it right in the end. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably an illusion. JavaScript closures were made for this, you will never get a `ReferenceError` for `x` with the code you posted above. This doesn't mean `x` can't be `undefined`.

Comment: yeah, @pablochan showed me the truth :) next time i'll be careful. just from the ethics point... should i mark your answer as right, or should i answer this myself and say i was wrong ?

Comment: Do as it pleases you, my answer is not harmful at least, but it doesn't describe specifically where you were wrong. I suggest you make your own answer